# How to get the length of navigation path

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,I wanna get the length of navigation path when I use nav_msgs/GetPlan.

Do I have to calculate the distance between every two adjacent points in the array (nav_msgs/Path -> geometry_msgs/PoseStamped[] poses) ?

I mean, in real-time. The remaining length varies depending on the robot position.

My poor way is to calculate distance of every two points, and add them up...

Is there a more convenient method ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290553/how-to-get-the-length-of-navigation-path/) by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you hit the nail on the head. You've got to calculate the length of each straight path segment and add them up.

Working out how much of a path is left to traverse is slightly trickier because the robot will probably not be 'exactly' on the path. Path progress can be found by calculating the closest point on the path to the robot's position. This is a bit more work but then allows you to accurately measure how far along the path your robot is.

Although the code to do this is more than a couple of lines you will have no problem at all calculating this in real time.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) on 2018-05-07**:
Thanks for your response,I'll try to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem by adding neighbors.

This is core of my mind:

```
rospy.Subscriber("/move_base/NavfnROS/plan", Path, callback)
```

and in callback:

```
sum_ += sqrt(pow((data.poses[i+1].pose.position.x - data.poses[i].pose.position.x),2) + pow((data.poses[i+1].pose.position.y - data.poses[i].pose.position.y), 2))
```

It works well.
:)

---

Originally posted by [TifferPelode](https://answers.ros.org/users/27959/tifferpelode/) with karma: 96 on 2018-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44686/dimi/) on 2019-08-09**:
TifferPelode could you demonstrate precisely that piece of your code (i.e. callback) ?